# Sveltekit : really long to send the first page and intense CPU computation

Tags: performance, sveltekit

I created a fairly basic Sveltekit project from the official project creation tool (+I installed flowbite-svelte, dexiejs and a few very basic stuff), but when I start the project with `npm run dev`, it very quickly prints

```
> 2024-03-sveltekit@0.0.1 dev
> vite dev

Port 5173 is in use, trying another one...

  VITE v5.2.6  ready in 821 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5174/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h + enter to show help
```

but when I try to load my first page, it will take maybe 30s to load it, and the CPU will compute like crazy. In my previous experience with, e.g., vite + react, everything was starting really quickly so I'm quite surprised. Any idea what's going on here?